# Why am I having trouble reading photos on my Canon 550D via USB with standard Mac software?

Tags: canon-550d, macintosh, usb

I have a Canon 550D that I want to connect via USB to my Mac, but I'd rather not install all this Canon software. However when I connect it nothing happens on the Mac, and iPhoto and Finder see nothing.

Is there a way to see my photos without installing Canon stuff?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to install the Canon stuff; or at the least the Canon Utility?

Comment: I don't like this kind of software, usually bad quality and most of the time not needed (since iPhoto works)

Comment: iPhoto now opens instantly and sees photos, I think it's because it was launched the first time, thus badly configured. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get a SD-Card reader (or use the one in your MacBook pro if you have one)
2. Have you tried "Image Capture" – there's some settings that will set default behavior of what happens when you connect the camera.
3. Have you tried iPhoto?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Mac and a 550D/T2i and when I connect my camera (without having installed the software), the camera/photos show in iPhoto. Try plugging the camera in while it is OFF, opening iPhoto, switching the camera ON, and then hitting the "Play" button on your camera that you use to review photos.

You shouldn't need to install the software at all. I eventually did because I like using it for remote capture, but your Mac should have the appropriate drivers already to detect the 550D.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I solved the problem now iPhoto sees the camera (see my answer)

Comment: I saw it right after I posted it, hah. I'm glad you discovered the issue. If you're interested in any sort of studio photography or video, I would highly encourage you to at least install the EOS Utility software. Put the CD in and choose custom install. Check only the box for the EOS Utility. I think it was something like 5MB...nothing too large. Happy shooting :)

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac, preferences for what happens when you plug in a camera or a memory card, are controlled by an app called "Image Capture". iPhoto, Lightroom, etc can automatically put preference settings here, but sometimes they do not get done.

Plug in your 550D, then:

1. Search Spotlight (apple+spacebar)
   for Image Capture. Select it and
   run.
2. You should see your 550D in
   the main screen. Select it.
3. At
   bottom left, you will see some
   options for the 550D: Select the
   application you wish to run when the
   camera is connected (or import).

TIP #1: If you wish to NOT have anything pop up, you can choose 'No application' to keep iPhoto or other app from opening when you plug in your camera or card

TIP #2: If you want to stop iPhoto from opening when you plug in your iPhone or iPad, follow steps above when your iPhone or iPad is connected and see TIP #1

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto now opens instantly and sees photos, I think it's because it was launched the first time, thus badly configured.